# Owl-carousel not working after dynamic population

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding images to my owl-carousel dynamically, like this:

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myObj.small_images.length; i++) {
  var src = myObj.small_images[i];
  $(".prev-owl-carousel").append("<div class='more-views-items'><a href='#' class='prevImg' data-image='" + src + "' data-zoom-image='" + src + "'><img id='product-zoom' src='" + src + "' alt='product-image'></a></div>");
}
```

I am getting the valid HTML, but the owl-carousel does not initialize (it is not adding special classes and styles).
This is how I do the owl-carousel itself:

```js
$(".prev-owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  autoplay: false,
  items: 4, //10 items above 1000px browser width
  itemsDesktop: [1024, 3], //5 items between 1024px and 901px
  itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 2], // 3 items betweem 900px and 601px
  itemsTablet: [600, 3], //2 items between 600 and 0;
  itemsMobile: [320, 2],
  navigation: true,
  navigationText: ["<a class=\"flex-prev\"></a>", "<a class=\"flex-next\"></a>"],
  slideSpeed: 500,
  pagination: false
});
```

I need to add the images dynamically and create valid owl-carousel, what's the problem?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console? Does the carousel plugin support dynamically adding new items or do you fully-reinitialize the plugin after each add? It might be helpful to create a stackblitz/plnkr/jsfiddle example showcasing the problem

Comment: No errors in the Console. Images in HTML are set, but not even showing in browser.

Comment: Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/640335/ of what is achieved

Comment: No `owlCarousel` is initialized in your linked jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry about that http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/640341/